# How to restore consecutively more than one session in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, model, neural-network

I want to restore multiple models with the same structure but different learning rates etc.

What I am stuck on is that I cannot run the restore function twice in a row. If I comment tt1 and run tt2 or the vice versa I can get my desired prediction, but if I run them both together this is not possible.

```
def predict(data, features, submodel_type, ckpt):
    n_input, weights, biases, X_test, Y_test = init(data, submodel_type, features)
    x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
    pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver.restore(sess, ckpt)
        X_test_scale = preprocessing.scale(X_test)
        pred_y = sess.run(pred, feed_dict={x: X_test_scale})
        gMAE, gMRE = evaluate('TT', pred_y, Y_test)
        print("GMRE:", gMRE)
        print("GMAE:", gMAE)
        for v1, v2 in zip(pred_y, Y_test):
            print('PV: %.2f, TV: %.2f, ERR: %.d' % (v1, v2, abs(v1 - v2)))
    sess.close()
    return pred_y, Y_test


data = np.genfromtxt('/home/simeonv/PycharmProjects/TotalTime/data/TEST SET DO NOT USE/test.csv', delimiter=',',
                     dtype=float)
features_0000 = [6,...89]
features_0001 = [0, .... 5,89]
submodel_0000 = '0000'
submodel_0001 = '0001'
ckpt_0000 = '/../TT_0000_2018_7_27_134233_MAE_1395.0954.ckpt'
ckpt_0001 = '/../TT_0001_2018_7_27_153715_MAE_1526.3000.ckpt'

tt1 = predict(data, features_0000, submodel_0000, ckpt_0000)
tt2 = predict(data, features_0001, submodel_0001, ckpt_0001)
```

How can I make it work? I tried `sess.close` but it does not work since I tought is beacause the session is still running with some leftover values.

The error that I get when I run both tt1 and tt2 is:

```
ValueError: Variable h1 already exists, disallowed. 
Did you mean to set reuse=True or reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope? Originally defined at:

File "/home/TT/TT_0001/TT_0001.py", line 26,
 in init'h1': tf.nn.l2_normalize(tf.get_variable(name='h1', shape=[n_input, n_hidden_1], initializer=init), axis=[0]),
File "/home/TT/TT_0001/TT_0001.py", line 94,
 in predict n_input, weights, biases, X_test, Y_test = init(data, submodel_type, features)
File "/home/TT/TT_0001/TT_0001.py", line 124,
 in <module> tt1 = predict(data, features_0000, submodel_0000, ckpt_0000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem, I do not know if it is a good solution but it works.

```
tt1 = predict(data, features_0000, submodel_0000, ckpt_0000)
tf.reset_default_graph()
tt2 = predict(data, features_0001, submodel_0001, ckpt_0001)
```

By resetting the graph I can start the new session without a problem.